# How to use sum in a where clause to calculate a avg

Tags: postgresql, postgis, average

I'm still new to sql, i'have just been using postgresql for a week. I am a little stucked..

I'm using the NY dataset ( http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/about_data.html ).

I have to find a way to list all the neighborhoods with more asian population than the average of corresponding borough and i have to display the percentage of asian population.

I thought about this :

```
select name, 100 * sum(c.popn_asian)/(select (avg(popn_asian)) from nyc_census_blocks group by boroname)
from nyc_neighborhoods n, nyc_census_blocks c
where (ST_Contains(n.geom, c.geom) = true )
and (sum(c.popn_asian)) > (select avg(popn_white) from nyc_census_blocks c1 group by c1.boroname)
```

But i am not aloud to use sum after the where clause apparently... I'd like to know why and learn how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: hows it going with this?

Answer (score 5):

```
select name, 100 * sum(c.popn_asian)/(select (avg(popn_asian)) from nyc_census_blocks group by boroname)
from nyc_neighborhoods n, nyc_census_blocks c
where ST_Contains(n.geom, c.geom) = true 
group by name
having sum(c.popn_asian) > (select avg(popn_white) from nyc_census_blocks c1 group by c1.boroname)
```

Comment: It does not work. It says there can not be more than one outcome for and understatement.
    select avg(popn_asian) from nyc_census_blocks c1 group by c1.boroname    
(its not white but asian but that will not change anything). I guess this is the problem, the avg(popn_asian) has to be above the average of the borough where the neighborhood is in, so I guess I need to add something as
    like c1.boroname = n.boroname 
but that does not work either...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `having` clause for this issue.